# Como fazer uma verificação ternária de <checkbox> com PHP?

Tags: php, array, formulário, checkbox

Estou fazendo esta verificação num campo `<select>` e tudo está a correr bem mas eu gostaria de fazer a mesma verificação em uma `<checkbox>` que pode ter várias possibilidades precisando então trabalhar com `arrays` então não sei como proceder.

Abaixo o código que uso para `<select>`:

**PHP**

```
if( isset( $_POST['valorminimo'] ) ) $_SESSION['valorminimo'] = $_POST['valorminimo'];
```

**HTML**

```
<option value="1mil" <?php echo (($valormaximo == '1mil') ? 'selected="selected"' : ""); ?>>1mil</option>
```

Agora eu tenho o código `PHP` abaixo para as `checkboxes` que recupera os índices corretamente e preciso saber no `HTML` como fazer uma verificação ternária para aplicar um efeito no `checked`.

**PHP**

```
$dorms = isset( $_SESSION['dorms'] ) ? $_SESSION['dorms'] : array();
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="dorm1" class="hidden drm" type="checkbox" name="dorms[]" value="1" <?php ((in_array($dorms)) ? "checked='checked'" : "" ); ?>>                                   
<input id="dorm2" class="hidden drm" type="checkbox" name="dorms[]" value="2">                                  
<input id="dorm3" class="hidden drm" type="checkbox" name="dorms[]" value="3+">
```

> Resumindo: como verificar em cada `input type checkbox` se ele está `checked` ou não?

Comment: usando foreach no `$_POST['dorms']`, as checkboxes não selecionadas nem serão enviadas ao servidor (se eu não me engano)...

Comment: Pode demonstrar numa resposta por favor?

Comment: Me perdi um pouco, você quer fazer essa verificação do lado do cliente (HTML) ou servidor (PHP) pois não vejo em seus códigos indícios de que esses valores vão pro servidor...

Comment: Quero verificar no retorno do PHP se esses campos são "checked" ... dá uma olhada nessa página que tem a busca e abaixo os dados retornados da busca ... http://new.pier36imoveis.com.br/busca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os checkboxes que não foram marcados não serão enviados para o servidor, mas dependendo do contexto que essa aplicação funciona é necessário checar o valor do checkbox, para evitar transtornos futuros.

Supondo que o nome da variável que você deu `var_dump` seja `$valores`

```
if(isset($valores['dorms']) && is_array($valores['dorms']) && !empty($valores['dorms'])) { // verificações básicas
    foreach($valores['dorms'] as $key => $dorm) { // percorre a array
        if(!empty($dorm)) { // verifica se não está vazio
            echo 'O checkbox de índice ['.$key.'] e valor ['.$dorm.'] foi marcado';
        }
    }
}
```

e só...

Comment: Ainda não entendi como aplicar isto no meu código. O que eu enviei pro servidor mostrar os dados foi `<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION);  ?>`

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Sim, no caso era só substituir `$valores` por `$_SESSION`, ou `$valores = $_SESSION;`